# How to override the objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Some quick background that i am working below is sample ObjectDataSource .

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objectDataSourceAdmin" runat="server" SelectMethod="SelectOrgsActive" TypeName="Business.OrganisationComponent" OnSelecting="ObjectDataSource1_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="OrgID" Type="String" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="ClientID" Type="String" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="IsActive" Type="Boolean" DefaultValue="True" />
     </SelectParameters>
```

- One Dropdown on my page that is bind form `objectDataSource`. I want that when Administrator Login then the dropdownlist will bind with `objectDataSourceAdmin`. But when   client login then i want to use different `objectDataSourceClient`.

Comment: It seems like your logic should be in the code-behind rather than on your page. Is there any reason you can't do that? If nothing else, it just seems simpler.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen thanks for your is any possibility to use different Objectdatasource